# Kivy NavigationDrawer right side menu

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I'm trying to implement a menu using Kivy's [NavigationDrawer](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.navigationdrawer), within a NavigationDrawer SidePanel. However, all examples and code I've seen have the menu on the left side of the screen. How can I place the SidePanel on the right side of the screen instead of the left side of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't right now, but it wouldn't be very hard to change it. You can read the code of NavigationDrawer to see how it works and what parameters you'd need to change.

There's a pull request on the github repository that implements this, but as I remember it had some small bugs. You can look at its code to see what you'd need to change, or use it directly.

Comment: Thanks inclement. That's exactly what I was looking for. And thanks for making such a useful addon for kivy.